# Centos multiple hosting ssh

Tags: apache, centos, server, centos6, vhosts

I would like to use multi hosting for my various domains . Now use centos 6.5 and ssh . If now point to my ip , gives me the main website , I would like to point to the correct folder in each domain hosting.

How can i point multiple domains with centos 6.5 and ssh ?

```
My idea :
onesiteweb.com
twositeweb.com
3siteweb.com
ecc
```

I have settings httpd.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@laxxxx.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/laxxxx.com
ServerName laxxxx.com
ServerAlias www.laxxxx.com
ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/laxxxxx.com/error_log
CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/laxxxx.com/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

But i see main website only when i go website...

Comment: Assuming you mean your websites you view in the browser this has nothing to do with ssh and everything to do with your webserver configuration. Are you using apache?

Comment: Yes i use apache, my path is /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/

Comment: you can use Virtaulhost for the same.!!

Comment: The problems was httpd.conf. Now work.